# %~1 and %1 Automatically Removing Everything after the first Space

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I am creating a batch file to store a selected folder's path into a text file to refer to it later on using another batch script...

I created registry entries to include a right-click context menu for any folder which triggers this specific batch file.

Basically When you right click a folder and click "Send to Script" it is supposed to copy the whole path / location of the right clicked folder.

To do so I am using the following command:

`SET TargetDir=%~1`

I also tried using `%1`and I also tried using the following code with delimiters

```
FOR /f "delims=;" %%a in ("%~1") do (
    @echo %%a
)
```

**The problem** is that CMD is automatically trimming everything after the first space and since this is a path I am copying, I want to keep all the spaces and the path as is

***Ex.*** If I use the command on a Folder such as **"C:/folder/subfolder"** the copyng is done correctly But If I use the command on a Folder such as **"C:/folder/sub folder"** the copying is done incorrectly and will only give me ***"C:/folder/sub"*** removing all the rest found after the first space detected.

**Registry Entries**

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\send-to-script]
"MUIVerb"="Send To Script"
"SubCommands"="sendscript"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\sendscript]
@="Send To Script"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\sendscript\command]
@="C:\\scripts\\pathtotext.bat %1"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show also your registry entry. Perhaps you only need to add quotes around `"%1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your registry key `[...\sendscript\command]` to

```
@="C:\\temp\\blob.bat \"%1\""
```

And in your batch you should use

```
REM The DisableDelayedExpansion is for preserve "!" in path names
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "TargetDir=%~1"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    echo target is !TargetDir!
) > C:\scripts\target.log

if "reseverdFolder" == "!TargetDir!" echo This folder is reserved
```

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same error >>  folder==xC:\folder\sub was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Eric As said, without showing your code, I can only say that you have a bug in your code

Comment: Just solved it, Your solution is good @jeb and in-fact it works. I was just missing a pair of double quotes "" resulting in the string not being wrapped so the batch file was breaking spaces... But overall your registry entry modification and batch code works as a charm. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The batch file is not correct registered. For example look with *regedit* on value of registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtffile\shell\open\command
```

The value is displayed as:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\WORDPAD.EXE" "%1"
```

So there are two arguments which are both enclosed in double quotes:

1. Argument **0** is the application to run with full path, file name and file extension enclosed in double quotes as path contains a space character.
2. Argument **1** is the name of the RTF file referenced with `%1` passed by Windows Explorer with full path, file name and file extension which of course can also contain a space or any of the characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which require also enclosing entire argument in double quotes as output by `cmd.exe` on running it in a command prompt window with `cmd /?` on last help page.

So you need in your *.reg file used to import into Windows registry:

```
@="\"C:\\scripts\\pathtotext.bat\" \"%1\""
```

This string value is displayed in registry editor as:

```
"C:\scripts\pathtotext.bat" "%1"
```

And then you can use `%1` or `%~1` in your batch file as explained by help of command **CALL** output on running in a command prompt window on execution of `call /?`.

Comment: Thanks for such info @Mofi. Really helpful as I was messing some things up in the reg resulting in obviously not matching the batch

Answer (score 1):

```
SET "TargetDir=%*"
```

Since the parameter apparently being supplied is `C:\folder\sub folder` then `%~1` selects only the first supplied parameter of what `cmd` sees as two parameters.

`%*` means "the whole tail"

and `echo`ing `%*` should show you exactly what `cmd` is seeing.

Comment: First of all thanks for your fast reply... the * seemed to do the trick without the ~ so I used SET "TargetDir=%*" without the ~, and I can see the full path with spaces when I echo it but some kind of error now seems to be happening because of the space in the path as the batch script is exiting on the next step which is to save the variable into a text file. It quits only when the path has spaces. On the other hand the path will be copied to the text file if there are no spaces at all... Thanks again for your help ;)

Comment: The error I am getting is >> 
folder==xC:\folder\sub was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You should show more of your batch code, else we need to guess that your `if folder==%TargetDir%` fails

Comment: The `%*` solution works good until a path contains an ampersand `Documents & Sheets`